# Hide loader on all API executed

Tags: angular

I am working on a angular Project with multiple modules. I am trying to show a loader on a load of each page and only hide the loader once the request for all the API call is completed for that page.

So, my problem won't be solved just by showing a loader right after onInit is called and hide it after all the request is completed.

suggest me a best option so i can show and hide loader on all api executed.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.function1();
    this.function2();
    this.function3();
}

function1(){
    this.spinner.show();
    // API code here.. 
    this.spinner.hide();
}

function2(){
    this.spinner.show();
    // API code here.. 
    this.spinner.hide();
}

function3(){
    this.spinner.show();
    // API code here.. 
    this.spinner.hide();
}
```

Comment: Can you create a Stackblitz example?

Comment: When you say you want to show a loader on page load, the page load in context of angular is ngOnInit lifecycle hook. what do you mean by " my problem won't be solved just by showing a loader right after onInit?"

Comment: @Rajat can't create an example.

Comment: @MehdiShakeri i'm using "this.spinner.show()" on function call and using "this.spinner.hide()" for hide.. here problem is that Loader blinks again and again on all API so i would like to use a common  "this.spinner.show()" and "this.spinner.hide()" on all API executed

Comment: So why your problem can't be solved by this solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135784/how-to-implement-a-global-loader-in-angular/66917696#66917696

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

`component.ts`

```js
public isLoading: boolean;

ngOnInit() {

    this.isLoading = true;
    this.myBackendCode().finally(()=> this.isLoading = false;);
}

private async myBackendCode() {
   // code here...
}
```

`component.html`

Use your loader like this, in this example is **mat-spinner**.

```html
<mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoading"></mat-spinner>
<app-something *ngIf="!isLoading"></app-something>
```

Comment: I have tried but it hides before API completion.

Comment: So please, put your code example like I did so that we can see the problem.

Comment: Updated question so you can check.

Comment: The only reason to code `this.spinner.hide()` runs before the "API code" is you are running in Async mode. Add some console.debug("api completed") before `hide()` and console.debug("hide run") after it. Check what comes first.