# Add animation to the refresh button in the grid Angular

Tags: html, angular, components, observable, subscribe

When there is no updated data in a grid, the refresh button will visualy do nothing. This is confusing for the user, so i want to add an animation to the button during the reload of the grid. Use the font-awsome way.

HTML:

```
    <hum-button
  [tooltipContent]="'GridComponent.refreshGrid' | translate"
  iconCss="fa fa-refresh"
  [isPrimary]="true"
  [onlyIcon]="true"
  (click)="onRefreshGridClick()"
>
</hum-button>
```

Angular:
grid.component.ts

```
public refreshData(): void {
if (typeof this.refreshGridFn === 'function') {
  this.refreshGridFn();
  return;
}

if (this.agGrid) {
  return this.agGrid.refreshData();
}
```

}

Angular: ag-grid.component.ts

```
  public refreshData(): void {
if (!this.customDatasource) {
  this.log('refreshData');
  if (this.dataSource && this.dataSource.rowCount > 0) {
    this.gridApi.refreshInfiniteCache();
  } else {
    this.gridApi.purgeInfiniteCache();
  }
}
```

}

[this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3EIN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're several options.

One of then is using .css. If you defined

```
.rotate {
  animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

You can use some like

```
<mat-icon [class.rotate]="loading">refresh</mat-icon>
```

And put the variable loading to true/false

You can also use Angular animations:

```
animations:[
    trigger('rotate', [
    transition('void=>*',[style({transform:'rotate(0)'})]),
    transition ('* => *', [
      style({ transform: 'rotate(0)' }),
      animate ('650ms ease-in-out',style ({ transform: 'rotate(360deg)' }),
      ),
    ])
  ])
```

You use

```
<mat-icon [@rotate]="count" 
     (@rotate.done)="loading && count=count+1>refresh</mat-icon>
```

And define two variables

```
count:any;
loading;
```

When you want to start

```
this.count=this.count!=1?1:0
this.loading=true
```

When finished

```
this.loading=false
```

In the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-material-starter-template-jsejka?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) you has the two options (just click the buttons to start/end animation)

**Update**

Well, we want to use when call to an API. So I imagine a service that return an observable

We has two approach:

1. Using a variable and finalize rxjs operator.

   ```
     getData()
     {
       this.loading=true;
       this.count=this.count==1?0:1
       this.dataService.getData().pipe(finalize(()=>{
         this.loading=false
       })
       ).subscribe(res=>this.data=res)
     }
   ```
2. Other approach is use an operator indicate as it's how in this
   [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135784/how-to-implement-a-global-loader-in-angular/66917696#66917696) (that sadly had a little attention) This operator need a
   Subject, so the functions becomes like

   ```
     getAllData()
     {
       this.count2=this.count2==1?0:1
       this.dataService.getData().pipe(indicate(this.loading$,0)
       ).subscribe(res=>this.data=res)

     }
   ```

   But the .html it's a bit complex

   ```
   <!-using css-->
   <button mat-button (click)="getAllData()">
        <mat-icon [class.rotate]="loading$|async">
            refresh
        </mat-icon>
   </button>

   <!--using Angular animations-->
   <button mat-button (click)="getAllData()">
     <ng-container *ngIf="{loading:loading$|async} as load">
     <mat-icon [@rotate]="count2" 
               (@rotate.done)="load.loading && count2=count2+1">
        refresh
     </mat-icon>
   </ng-container>
   </button>
   ```

The advantage of use an operator is that you can use with any observable -even the rxjs operator `of`-

I just update the stackblitz

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i would like the button to automatically stop spinning when the page or data is already loaded

Comment: @Momen, I update the answer and the stackblitz

Comment: I haven't had the chance to test it yet sadly, but I think your way is the right one so I'm gonna accept this as the answer and hopefully get back to it soon, thank you