# Rxjs / Angular 8: HTTPHandler doesn't get triggered when calling Subscription.unsubscribe()

Tags: angular, rxjs, httprequest

I need to `unsubscribe` during a call but when I do this there is no `HttpResponse`. This is a problem for me as I also am using an `http` interceptor to catch when I should show a loading icon or not.

So in my specific component I have this:

```
 if (this.testSubscription)
    this.testSubscription.unsubscribe();  // Stop original http request when calling getTestDetails with other parameters
  this.testSubscription = this.getTestDetails(param1, param2);
```

And my interceptor:

```
 intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
this.totalRequests++;
console.log(' intercept totalRequests: ', this.totalRequests);
this.loadingService.isLoading.next(true);
return next.handle(request).pipe(
  tap(res => {
    if (res instanceof HttpResponse) {
    //  I need to get here even when unsubscribing !!!!
        this.decreaseRequests();
    }
  }),
  catchError(err => {
    this.decreaseRequests();
    throw err;
  })
);
}
```

So I'm not really sure how I can trigger my intercept method to catch this when I `unsubscribe` on the  Subscription..
Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: You can use `finalize` that is triggered also when you unsubscribe but in that case you won't have access to any `next` in case it passed successfully.

Comment: Generally, you could use `switchMap` to smoothly unsubscribe from one stream and subscribe to another.

Comment: Martin's comment was an easy fix, thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code looks [vaguely familiar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51813213/894273). :D

As @martin pointed out, you can use the `finalize` operator. In fact, I've done some testing and found out you don't even need to `tap` operator to handle all use-cases:

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(
  finalize(() => {
    this.totalRequests--;
    if (this.totalRequests === 0) {
      console.log('set loading false');
    }
  })
);
```

I've updated the original answer to reflect this info.

PS: The solution you came up with might have a bug in case of an error. If you have two pending requests and one of them fails while the other one is still in progress, you'll have `decreaseRequests()` run twice (one from `catchError` operator and one from `finalize`), which will set loading to `false` even though there still is another request pending.

Comment: Ow alright, good of you to point that out!  This will be a cleaner solution as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments I was able to fix my problem.
I've changed my interceptor to:

```
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
this.totalRequests++;
this.loadingService.isLoading.next(true);
return next.handle(request).pipe(
  tap(res => {
  //Removed code here
  }),
  catchError(err => {
    this.decreaseRequests();
    throw err;
  }),
  finalize(() => {
    if(this.totalRequests > 0){
      this.decreaseRequests();
  }  }
  )
);
```

}

I've tested it thoroughly and it seems to be working for my purposes.