# How to block UI until all pending operations are complete?

Tags: angular, ngx-spinner

I have an Angular 8 web app with [NgxSpinner](https://github.com/Napster2210/ngx-spinner). I'm using it to block UI when some lengthy process is in progress to prevent users from interacting with complex forms while some parts haven't yet fully loaded.

The problem is that NgxSpinner hides itself immediately if some process calls `hide`, no matter if there is still another process with its own `show/hide` call pair running. So, the web page is unblocked too early when any shorter process has been completed and has called `spinner.hide()`.

Here's [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-enob1r?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) example.

**How do I make the NgxSpinner to wait for the last `hide` to match all `show` calls?**

P.S. It seems an issue with many UI block libraries I've tried - they just don't account for parallel processes calling `show/hide` multiple times.

Comment: As i think, you can add one counter in your service, increment on every process call, and when it complete decrement it. once it is zero then you can call spinner.hide() method. Hope you understand it .  The Stackblitz page i am not able to access.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular show spinner for every HTTP request with very less code changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385369/angular-show-spinner-for-every-http-request-with-very-less-code-changes)

Comment: @akpgp    thanks, it gave the idea about reference count implementation. I hoped there would be something built-into UI blocker, but apparently there isn't and I'll have to wrap the NgxSpinner inside my own refcounting service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create one service for spinner and keep show/hide count there.

```
export class MySpinnerService {
  showIndex = 0;
  hideIndex = 0;

  constructor(private spinner: NgxSpinnerService) {}

  show() {
    this.showIndex++;
    this.spinner.show();
    console.log('show spinner', this.showIndex);
  }

  hide() {
    this.hideIndex++;
    if (this.showIndex === this.hideIndex) {
      this.spinner.hide();
      console.log('hide spinner', this.hideIndex);      
    }
  }
```

So when `showIndex`  and `hideIndex` equals you need to hide spinner.

Call in your component

```
this.mySpinner.show(); // show spinner
this.mySpinner.hide(); // hide spinner
```

Here is example in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wnchxx).

Answer (score 0):

you can make a use of Promise. Each Process function will return a promise and then you can make a use of Promise.all function which will be called once all the promise is resolved. you can hide the spinner in promise.all method.
Please find below the sample code.

```
this.spinner.show();
let p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve();
  }, 3000);

});

let p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve();
  }, 3000);

});

Promise.all([p1,p2]).then( ()=> {
  this.spinner.hide();
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not that simple in real life. My StackBlitz code was very simplified example. Actually the spinner is shown and hidden all over the place in many services and components and I just want to ensure that the spinner doesn't hide until the last call of `hide`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use forkJoin operator, in this case you will enter in this state when all requests are completed and then you will hide your loading spinner

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not that simple in real life. My StackBlitz code was very simplified example. Actually the spinner is shown and hidden all over the place in many services and components and I just want to ensure that the spinner doesn't hide until the last call of hide.